# Are dustproof screen protectors for real?

Tags: ios, screen

With search engines, I can find supposedly dustproof screen protectors for sale?
e.g.:
http://www.amazon.ca/Clear-Scratch-Resistant-Screen-Protectors/dp/B003JBRSXY
[http://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-Protector-Washable-Resistant/dp/B00A2A0D7S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A2A0D7S)

Do these screen protectors actually repel dust? Do they actually end up less dusty than other screens/screen protectors?

Comment: Nothing to do with Apple products.

Comment: These comments seem to misunderstand the scope of the site.  Our [help pages](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly say that questions about "third-party hardware... when associated for use with Apple products" are on-topic.  Questions asking for shopping/buying recommendations are [always off-topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), but I don't think this quite falls into that topic; this question is asking about a general categories of products and asks whether they are "for real" (whether they actually work), which I think is OK.

Comment: I'm wondering if this would be a better question for the product page on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A2A0D7S/#ask-inline-widget)?

Comment: Why are you so concerned about dust? You should really be scared of the oils from your hands instead.

Comment: I am more persnickety than concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of these protectors is not to keep dust off the screen protector but the device. They are Scratch/Dust resistant. With all protector, they will get scratch, your device will not. That is what they are say, not that it will help your screen, but your device.